# PHP Mysql to create a Pipe delimeted output file

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the below for csv export but i want to export as a pipe delimeted.

```
function to_CSV($table) {

    $file_csv = "file_csv.csv";
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w'); 

    $query = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='htmltable' AND TABLE_NAME='$table'";
    $result = mysqli_query(db_connect(),$query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            $header[] = $row[0];
    }

    header('Content-type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_csv);
    fputcsv($fp, $header);

    $query  ="SELECT * from $table";
    $result = mysqli_query(db_connect(),$query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }
    exit;
}
```

Help me out please

Comment: RTFM http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php clearly shows the third parameter as the delimiter.

Comment: thanks for your info

Answer (score 1):

fputcsv accepts custom delimeter as third argument. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

For example:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row, '|');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fputcsv allows you to specify the delimiter

```
fputcsv($fp, $header,  "|");
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php